# Error: Cannot find module 'compression'

Tags: node.js

When I want to start my application it returns the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'compression'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.....\node_modules\webpack-dev- 
    server\lib\Server.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I have tried:

- `yarn install`
- `yarn upgrade`
- deleting `node_modules`
- etc...

But it's still not working. Can you help me please?

Comment: `yarn add compression` ?

Comment: Specification:

- compression package is installed in node_modules

Comment: manually delete node_modules and then `yarn install` again

Comment: I tried it all... and always the same problem.

Comment: maybe you can try cleaning of cache `yarn cache clean` and then `yarn install` or `yarn` again

Comment: It doesn't work. Same problem :-(

Comment: Solved > new project directory. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @DavidSlabý, could you please explain to me, I am alsostuck here

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to solve this problem by running `npm install --save @types/compression`

Comment: This wasn't exactly my problem, but helped me realize that I hadn't mounted all the relevant `package.json` files in my `docker run` command... so of course `yarn install` wasn't installing all the packages I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
npm i
```

This will install all missing node modules that are defined in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Install compression

`npm install compression --save`

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete:

- **node_modules**
- **package-lock.json**

and then run `npm i`.